# Problem with scaling drawing objects inside movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

So I've got problem with some drawing objects inside movieclip in my flash file... Setting width and height of flash to match browser's w&h got my movie clip to get correct values, but unfortunately drawing objects inside of it are not scaled as movieclip. Those object are just random stripes that got some tween on it acting as somekind of preloader... All graphics are pulled from ai file, so no AS was used to manipulate them, just pure tweening in design mode...

So if my stage w & h are lets say 720 x 50, graphics inside movieclip are 1600 x 900 which match my monitor's resolution.

How can I fix this?

Thx for all help! :)

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. What exactly do you want the end result to be? scaleX and scaleY will work but it will distort things if the resolution of the monitor and the resolution of the flash stage are different aspect ratios.

Comment: Well, my end result supposed to be fullscreen preloader, which supports resizing onresize. For know my graphics inside movieclip immediately has larger width and height compared to stage, so for stage 720x500, it has 1600x900, when I enter fullscreen it goes even beyond that dimension...

Answer (score 0):

try setting [`scaleX`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scaleX) and [`scaleY`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scaleY) instead of width/height

Comment: yes, but still graphic inside movieclip doing their own stuff... not listening to AS of their parent :/